# Get specific array element by matching key value in Twig

Tags: arrays, twig

I have an array of objects passed to Twig from PHP and I would like to print the value of a specific entry in the array that matches another value, i.e.:

```
{{ teams('id' == user.team_id).name }}
```

Here's what I'm doing currently - and this can't be right, there must be a simpler way:

```
{% for team in teams %}
  {% if team.id == user.team_id %}
    {{team.name}}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how your Controller (using Symfony?) looks like, but if the User is an object, you can simply use `{{ user.team.name }}`.

If that's not possible, you can use this:

```
{{ teams[user.team_id].name }}
```

[Documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables)

In case your the array keys don't match the `id`, you can even shorten your template:

```
{% for team in teams if team.id == user.team_id %}
    {{team.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah, of course, why didn't I think of that?  `{{user.team.name}}` works perfectly, thanks! :)